# Stacked Chart Web Part issue - contains gaps

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have the following SharePoint list:

[image]

I'm trying to use the long-time-ago deprecated Chart Web Part, but it is showing strange gaps between groups on the stacked bar. What is the reason and is there any way to get rid of those. Or is the Chart Web Part just this buggy? Using SharePoint 2016 with March 2024 CU.

[image]

With bit more data on the list, it will get real funky. Sure, this is test data and has lots of missing data, but still:

[image]

Will end up like this:

[image]